# What is this white web-like, mold-like thing on the plant

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, succulents, mold

what is this web-like, mold-like thing on the base of the watch chain succulent plant?

[image]

I searched in google for plant "molds" --> I saw powdery mildew. I think this is not that. It's more similar to a food mold. The plant has no insects, im sure of it, so i think it's not a web.

**A little bit of a background...**
I don't exactly know how and when it started to form. It sat in the office before, maybe around less than or a month.

Office env:

- temperature is ~21°C
- i think it might not be having enough sunlight as it is not near to a window

And then, one day, as I noticed the plant is starting to brown from the bottom, I checked the plant and saw these little white mold-like thing from the stem or the base of the plant.

For 2 days, in hope to save it from browning and to eliminate the mold, I placed it near a window to get sunlight and watered it in the morning. But the plant's condition did not improve. I didn't know what to do, there's water and sunlight, what else would it need?

I thought maybe it wants fresh air from an open space, so i brought it home and placed it in the balcony. I changed the watering schedule to once a week. I think it can get enough sunlight at home. I live in a tropical country, so the temperature is warm.

**Current Condition:**
No improvement. It is deteriorating. Almost all parts have browned except for the tips of the plant. The mold is still there.

Comment: it's a form of mycelium, if you let it grow out I may be able to identify it for you

Comment: @blackthumb ok, i will let it grow out and i will post some pictures here

Comment: could this be spiders?

Answer (score 2):

This is a soil mould digesting the organic matter in the soil. They only thrive where there is constantly damp or wet soil and not much air circulation. They do not affect the health of the plant.

You have reduced your watering which is good, move the plant to an area with more sunlight.

Is it possible there is no drainage from the pot the plant is in?  That would account for the deterioration of the plant due to root rot.

Comment: hi @kevinsky there is a drainage (there's a small hole at the bottom of the plant)

Comment: Have you seen water come through the drainage hole? I've seen them get blocked. Sometimes sticking a pencil or some such up through there and reaming it out will do wonders for actual drainage.

Comment: So I am wondering, Is there *any* soil mold that looks like this or similar to this that will harm the plant in any way?

Comment: Like I see all over the place that the mold eats organic matter. Does that mean roots? And if the mold has started growing on the green parts of my plant, does that mean that the mold is eating my plant? Or is it just attaching to the plant to hold onto something... And will this mold cause root rot or stem rot? Will it suffocate the plant?